# Can you store functions in an array and call them as needed?

Tags: arrays, swift, function

I am new to programming (1 week), so this maybe a silly question, but here goes...

Using Swift (on the XCode program) I have defined some functions (Func1, Func2 etc) which take an array of integers, and swaps certain values within the array. 
I have tried creating a new, separate array which contains Func1, Func2 etc , and then I would like to, based on a randomly generated number, (e.g. 10204), apply the functions as needed.

So, for example, the number 10204 would apply Func1, Func0, Func2, Func0, Func4 to the array.

I have tried looking at other questions on this site for ideas, but nothing seems to do the job, despite numerous attempts. Here is what I am trying to do - these two functions manipulate integers in an array called "cubePos"

```
func UC(){
        (cubePos[0] , cubePos[17])
        =
        (cubePos[17] , cubePos[19])
}

func DC(){
        (cubePos[26] , cubePos[41])
        =
        (cubePos[41] , cubePos[43])
}
```

Both of these functions work fine when I apply them myself. This is what I need to do next, define an array of the functions:

```
var arrOfFuncs = [UC , DC]
```

and then, given a number such as 10110, perform upon "cubePos" the equivalent of:

```
DC
UC
DC
DC
UC
```

When I put something like:

```
arrOfFuncs[0]
```

I would expect the code to apply UC() to the array "cubePos", but nothing seems to happen at all, despite UC () working fine when typed manually into the code.

Hoping someone can help!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted the code you are using in your question, so I created a basic sample which works. You can try using below code.

```
func one() {
    print("Hello 1")
}
func two() {
    print("Hello 2")
}

let arr = [one, two]

arr[0]

"10101".forEach {
    arr[Int(String($0))!]()
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I didn't really have code, was just trying all kinds of different things to see if I could get it to work as described in the question. I'll try it and see what happens